# Cannot run ASP.NET Core API after publishing on Debian

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created the basic ASP.Net Core API application that I want to run on debian through Apache, I didn't change anything from default app (that is generated when you create new project) except for .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>debian-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> <!-- NEW LINE -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I published it to folder (it created two folders: `netcoreapp2.0` and `PublishOutput`) and transfered it to debian. There I ran `sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.0.6` and tried to run `./MyAppName` in both directories (`PublishOutput` and `netcoreapp2.0/debian-x64`).

`PublishOutput` returned this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(String[] args)
   at MyAppName.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args)
   at MyAppName.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted
```

`netcoreapp2.0/debian-x64` returned this error:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (SrovnavacPojistoven.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
```

I'd be super happy if someone could help me. I couldn't find anything that worked. I've tried to publish basic .net core console application, that worked without any problem, I have problem only with ASP.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1502

Comment: Users suggested publishing from the command line: dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64

Comment: Thank you, helped!